# Smaller ultrasonic transceiver

Tags: arduino, transmitter, receiver, ultrasound, transceiver

I am a beginner working on my Arduino-based proximity sensor array project, like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILmK0DinkYM). I have already tested the functionality with single HC-SR04 transmitter/receiver and now I would like to build an array with, let’s say, 9 columns and 3 rows (27 transmitters, 27 receivers to connect to 54-pin Arduino Mega).

That HC-SR04 has a measure range from 2 cm to 400 cm with precision up to 3 mm (could be even higher with thermistor) and I want all of this to be downscaled: measure range from ideally 0 mm (3 mm are acceptable) to 30 mm with precision of ideally 0.1 mm (acceptable is 0.3 mm).

And I need these T/R merged into one casing – [like this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9495) and much smaller, let’s say 3 mm of width, but smallest available transceivers are about 8 mm wide.

Is there some physical limitation? Or is it because there is just no need for it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ultrasonics are defined by scale. The smaller it is the larger the frequency needed and the less amplitude, range and sensitivity you can achieve for a given drive voltage.

That translates into a trade-off. Smaller devices are possible, and probably even available, but the cost will go up due in part to fabrication costs and being a much smaller marketplace.